# Missing IAPs - although IAPs are "In Review"

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Apple rejected my app for the 4th time today for the following reason.

> Missing IAPs
>
> We are unable to complete the review of your app since one or more of your In App Purchases have not been submitted for review. While the binary contains several In-App Purchases, you have only submitted two for review.
>
> Please be sure to take action and submit your In App Purchases AND upload a new binary in iTunes Connect. Learn more about submitting In App Purchases for review in the In-App Purchase Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect.

I already submitted all my In-app purchases. I have 187 iaps with the status "In Review". In addition to that, in the app's "View details" page, I cannot find a place to submit any iaps, probably because all my iaps are already submitted and "In Review".

Some details about the app:
The app offers a new issue of a newspaper on a daily basis. The user can choose to buy the issue. I have created an individual iap for each issue, even for future issues that will be accessible by the user on their corresponding day.

I have ran out of solutions for this. I do not know what to do to avoid a 5th rejection. Help on this would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Did you actually include them when you fill out the metadata for your application?  There is a section for you to check which IAPs to include in your application.

Comment: Yes I did incllude all iaps. Now, since I incleaded all 187 iaps, I am not able to include them again. So the section "In-App purchases" on the "view details" page is not available anymore.

Comment: The appeal the rejection, and ask why.  We have no way of knowing from here.

Comment: I guess that's my only choice for now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: As far as I know, IAPs must be accepted before the app is submitted for review. Until they are approved, you don't use to submit the app.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion for the future - instead of individually listing your products, consider selling Tokens as a consumable IAP.  Once the user has purchased Tokens through the IAP system the user can exchange one or more Tokens for any of your App's products separate from the IAP system.

Things to consider when submitting IAPs for review versus sandbox and production use/testing: 
1) App Review only sees IAPs that have been attached to the binary, the sandbox sees all IAPs whether or not they have been attached
2) App Review may only see IAPs that have been marked 'cleared for sale'
3) App Review tests receipts in the sandbox environment not the production environment